# How can I make it so that CSS uses a class only if another is not present on an element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS classes:

```
button.current {
   background-color: #000;
}
button:hover {
   background: #0007d5;
}
```

How can I make it so the background color does not change for the second button? In other
words I want the current and the hover to one work if there's not an additional class of 
"inactive" on the button.

```
<button class="current">Show the current background</button>
<button class="current inactive">Show the current background</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/not.html) pseudo-class:

```
button.current:not(.inactive) {
   background-color: #000;
}
button:hover:not(.inactive) {
   background: #0007d5;
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/55Fjz/1/)